# Aspose.Cells - Set Border For Range

Tags: vb.net, formatting, aspose-cells

I'm currently working with Aspose.Cells. I've largely managed to do what I need to do however one issue remains; I can't see an easy way to apply a border to a defined range. I can for a cell, however when applying the style to the range all cells in the range are formatted.

The only way I can see around this is to write a method to enumerate all cells within the range to determine the right border attributes. This seems a slightly hideous way to achieve what I see as a simple task, so am hoping there is a better way!

Is there?

Comment: As there hasn't been a response, I will write the method described and post it here for future use.

Answer (score 1):

Ok let's start.
Assuming we want to add borders to a range from A2 cell to H6 cell range.
Always remember that cell index in Aspose is Zero based.
So the A2 cell has index of row 1 and column 0.

Define the range

`Dim range = current_worksheet.Cells.CreateRange(1, 0, 5, 8)`

Set the borders

```
    range.SetOutlineBorder(Aspose.Cells.BorderType.TopBorder,Aspose.Cells.CellBorderType.Thick,Drawing.Color.Blue)
range.SetOutlineBorder(Aspose.Cells.BorderType.BottomBorder,Aspose.Cells.CellBorderType.Thick, Drawing.Color.Blue)
range.SetOutlineBorder(Aspose.Cells.BorderType.LeftBorder,Aspose.Cells.CellBorderType.Thick, Drawing.Color.Blue)
range.SetOutlineBorder(Aspose.Cells.BorderType.RightBorder,Aspose.Cells.CellBorderType.Thick, Drawing.Color.Blue)
```

That's it!